# FIWARE OAuth2 Authentication in Python

Tags: python, oauth, fiware

I am trying to authenticate user using FIWARE.

It returns a 404. Thus fails at Step 1 itself. What is the access token url ? Any other pointers to check

I have tried variations with 'oauth/access_token', 'oauth/token' 'oauth2/token' 'oauth2/access_token' . All of them dont seem to work.

My Code is Below:

```
import oauth2 as oauth

# OAuth secret into your project's settings. 
consumer = oauth2.Consumer(settings.FIWARE_CLIENT_ID,settings.FIWARE_CLIENT_SECRET)
client = oauth2.Client(consumer)

access_token_url = 'https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/access_token'

# This is the slightly different URL used to authenticate/authorize.
authenticate_url = 'https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/authorize'


def fiware_login(request):
# Step 1. Get a request token from FIWARE.
resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "GET")
print resp
if resp['status'] != '200':
    print content
    raise Exception("Invalid response from FIWARE.")


# Step 2. Redirect the user to the authentication URL.
url = "%s?access_token=%s" % (authenticate_url,
    resp['access_token'])

return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct endpoint is "/oauth2/token".

Maybe you should use POST method instead of GET.

For more information see https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/wiki/Using-the-FI-LAB-instance